# How to switch off JavaScript programmatically only for Internet Explorer 7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I want to turn off JavaScript using JavaScript (and/or jQuery) code, only if the page is viewed in IE7.

How can this be done?

Would be grateful for the magic code snippet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check `if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 8)` and not run your code.

Comment: Turns it off in Firefox as well, for some reason. Any suggestions on how to make it work please?

Comment: Then you made a mistake.  What did you write?

Comment: if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version > 7) { //my code here }

Comment: Your condition is wrong.  You're only running your code if it's IE **and** it's `> 7`.  You want to run the code if it's **not** IE **or** it's `> 7`

Comment: Wait, I think I know what mistake I made. Bad logic on my part: it only displays in IE > 7.

Comment: Thanks, it almost worked. BUT: apparently, the site only displays when JS is off completely. How can I turn it off for the entire page?

Comment: I mean this: if IE 7: JS is off; else : JS is on. :-)

Comment: Thanks SLacks, your solution is the closest to what I needed. One more question though: how do I reverse your snippet, to make it say: "if the browser is NOT IE version 7" ?

Comment: You're probably looking for the `!` operator.

Comment: Yep, but how do I use it inside the but of code you helped me with? I tried if ($.browser.!msie && $.browser.version < !8) but it doesn't seem to work. What I want to say is: "unless it's EI7, run this code" :-) Help please? (Keep on mind, you're dealing with someone with a chronic case of a "beginner's mind".)

Comment: You want to run the code if it's not IE or it's `> 7`: `!$.browser.msie || $.browser.version > 7`

Comment: THANK YOU SLaks! You helped me a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Use conditional comments.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

```
<![if !(IE 7)]>
    // Script tags here
<![endif]>
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I know conditional comments, but what do I put inside <!-- [if IE 7] --> ? Would appreciate your advice on that.

Comment: You put your javascript code within those tags. !(IE 7) means not IE7, effectively all browsers except IE7.

Comment: Thank you Daniel - Colin - unfortunately it doesn't work with WordPress. Any suggestions on how to make it work?

Comment: what is the problem you are having

Comment: I'm having the problem of conditional comments not being recognized inside PHP page.

Comment: But, more widely, I'm having a problem of WordPress site not being displayed in IE7 when the JavaScript is on, so as a duct tape solution, I want to turn JS off only in IE7. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333143/jquery-code-obliterates-wordpress-site-in-internet-explorer-7

Answer (score 1):

You can´t turn JavaScript off. You can however exclude IE7 by using [Downlevel-revealed Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#dlrevealed).