# Is there a way of disabling jquery code when your website is viewed on mobile devices / tablets?

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, media-queries

I am coding a website that uses a lot of J-Query for animations / state changes. When viewed on mobile devices and tablets the J-Query becomes either very sluggish, or does not work at all. Is there a way of disabling the J-Query code on the site when its viewed on different devices, in the same way media queries allow you to use different CSS stylesheets for different devices?

Comment: Refer this, may get some clue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333878/how-to-switch-off-javascript-programmatically-only-for-internet-explorer-7

Comment: the above example is for changing Jquery according to the browser used. I am after changing the Jquery for different devices used (i.e different browser sizes)

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to check for a mobiledevice:

```
if(! /iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
    <THIS CODE WILL NOT BE EXECUTED ON MOBILE DEVICE>
}
```

U can place that direct into the (document).ready part and include all the code u dont want on mobile, or u place it around (document).ready if u dont need any jQuery code at all.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is server-side detection of mobile device and generating page without jquery. Take a look on this: http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/ and https://deviceatlas.com/